# Dynamically import Fontawesome icons from array in Svelte

Tags: svelte, font-awesome-5

I'm importing the icons using [svelte-fa](https://cweili.github.io/svelte-fa/?ref=madewithsvelte.com). There is no problem importing them manually and rendering inside my component like so:

```svelte
<script>
import { faDog, faCat } from '@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons';
</script>

<Fa icon={faDog} />
<Fa icon={faCat} />
```

However, I want to import 100 icons. I have a JS file with an array containing the names of the icons:

```svelte
export default [
  { icon: 'faDog', label: 'Dogs', id: 1 },
  { icon: 'faCat', label: 'Cats', id: 2 }
]
```

And then rendering them using an #each block:

```svelte
<script>
  import { faDog, faCat } from '@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons';
  import iconsData from '../icons.js';
</script>

{#each iconsData as icon }
  <Card label={icon.label} icon={icon.icon} />
{/each}
```

I can see the label of all the icons, but the icons are not showing. Is there a way around this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What does the `Card` component's source look like?